# How can I save only 'Show <> entries" state in datatables in HTML?

Tags: html, cookies, datatables

I am trying to save the state of showing entries in datatable but I cant, I tried by using `stateSave: true` and it works for saving the state for everything in the datable but in my case I just want to save the state for number of entries to show in a table.

Here is my entire code:

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>

<div class="content">
    <table id="dt-filter-select" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Dev.no</th>
                <th>IMEI</th>
                <th>Serial no.</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>Date added on stock</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Sales date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php if (!empty($devices)) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($devices as $device) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["device_no"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["serial_imei"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["serial_no"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["barcode"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["dev_name"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["created_date"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["name"] ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $device["sales_date"] ?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dt-filter-select').dataTable({
            initComplete: function() {
               stateSave: true,
                this.api().columns().every(function() {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select  class="browser-default custom-select form-control-sm"><option value="" selected>Filter</option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function() {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `stateSave: true,` one line up, before `initComplete: function() {`. both `stateSave` and `initComplete` are properties of the same object you need to pass as a parameter to `dataTable`.

Now you can check 'localstorage' with your browser developer tools.

- Explanation: [State Saving](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)
- save with a callback [stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback)
- load with callback [stateLoadCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback)

To save and load specific data, you need to adjust the `data` attribute you are passing to the callback functions.

Comment: I am sorry but how are you saving the state of the entries the way you are saying to do?

Comment: It is an automatic process done by the API [datatables.net: examples](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

Comment: I am already doing that, I am asking how to save the state of only one attribute, for example save the state of only Entries.

Comment: Call me a bit impatient, but you really need to read the docs. On the page I gave before there's a link [stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) with full explanation **and** example. Adjust the `data` parameter.

Comment: just post an explanation how would u do it (with code)

Comment: Not going to happen, I never use it, so I will need to read the docs first and adjust the example to only use one attribute instead of all. Something you can do too.